# Source maps files in production - Is it safe?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, sentry, source-maps, raven

I'm using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to minify and uglify my sources, and [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/docs/sourcemaps/) to report errors from my production environment.

In order to get errors from Sentry, in a readable manner, I need to add source-map

Is it safe to do it in production servers, or the source-maps files should only exist on staging environment?
Is there a way to secure them on production environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "safe". Are there sensitive details that would potentially be encoded in the source maps? The code has the same security whether it is uglified or not.

Comment: That's true, but I prefer that the source won't be easily viewed, in fact I would prefer that only getsentry, will be able to use the source maps, I know that it's doesn't add any real  security, but still I would like that my sources, apis, and internal logic would be hidden from the normal user ...

Comment: The normal user doesn't typically dig through the source code, and people who would think to dig through the source code to exploit you somehow won't be particularly deterred by obfuscation.

Comment: The number 1 reason programmers don't want others to look into their code is a lack of self-confidence. Be proud of what you create! As @PeterOlson says; normal users won't dig through, and if they did, they would understand the logics of Spaghetti better then your code. And other programmers will have de-obfuscated your code in seconds...

Comment: I'm a few years late to this discussion, but I thought I'd share a post I wrote a while ago about using source maps securely in a production environment. In my example, I'm using .NET Core but the same principle can be applied to any platform:
https://www.davidomid.com/using-production-source-maps-securely-in-aspnet-core

Comment: Very good question and reasonable answers, it is not opinion-based

Answer (score 60):

Searching for a possible solution to this, and if someone is not specifically using Sentry, I got to this blog post (ironically a Sentry blog post):

https://blog.sentry.io/2015/10/29/debuggable-javascript-with-source-maps.html

Where there is an interesting idea: "private source maps". It implies generating the source maps in someplace that is not accessible from the internet (such as your company VPN), so only you or your team can access the source maps files.

Quoting the **"Private Source Maps"** section of the post:

> [...] all of our examples assume that your source maps are publicly available, and served from the same server as your executing JavaScript code. In which case, any developer can use them to obtain your original source code.
>
> To prevent this, instead of providing a publicly-accessible sourceMappingURL, you can instead serve your source maps from a server that is only accessible to your development team. For example, a server that is only reachable from your company’s VPN.
>
> //# sourceMappingURL: http://company.intranet/app/static/app.min.js.map
>
> When a non-team member visits your application with developer tools open, they will attempt to download this source map but get a 404 (or 403) HTTP error, and the source map will not be applied.

Seems like a good idea to me!

Comment: Another idea is just use authentication, instead of relying on your source mapping URLs pointing to a separate server which isn't publicly accessible. I covered this solution in a blog post I released a while ago on using source maps securely in production: https://www.davidomid.com/using-production-source-maps-securely-in-aspnet-core

Answer (score 15):

Your primary concerns will be "is it ok if the user has my source code?" Usually it is fine, as users can deobfuscate things anyways.

That said, if you're using Sentry, you can actually use the [releases API](https://gist.github.com/dcramer/619d53dabfbc2ed008a1) to avoid this problem. You'll still need to generate the artifacts, and set URLs (or something that the API can handle), but you don't have to expose them to the internet.