# Can I place webpack source maps and source code files in seprate folders?

Tags: webpack, source-maps

I read this question [source maps files in production - is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345520/source-maps-files-in-production-is-it-safe). I want to generate source map files in different folders with source code. Is there any way to do this with webpack? I also read this thread [Relative SourceMap paths for debugging in WebStorm](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/238#issuecomment-144261479) and tested but failed again.

Comment: Did you mean *bunldes* and maps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`output.sourceMapFilename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputsourcemapfilename) like so:

```
output: {
    filename: "bundles/[name].[chunkhash].min.js",
    sourceMapFilename: 'maps/[name].[chunkhash].map.js'
},
```

and then serve only from the `bundles` folder.

Comment: ohhh thanks a lot. Really good answer and I believe I need to read the webpack guide from the very beginning again...

Comment: Ivan thanks for your answer. Maybe you can do it even better by adding a link to the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-sourcemapfilename).

Answer (score 13):

As Ivan wrote, the solution is to use `output.sourceMapFilename`

However, recommended solution from [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-sourcemapfilename) is to only use `[file]` placeholder (default value is `[file].map`).

It is then best to define the value as following:

```
output: {
    filename: 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'sourceMap/[file].map'
},
```

You will then preserve structure and it will also work for css sourceMaps

Comment: I find this suggestion very important, because sourcmap file name must match what referenced inside the minified file.