# tsc compiler option for output of .map files?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm trying to seperate my .map files from my .js files after transpiling. I have set the mapRoot so the debugger knows where to locate the map files. However I cannot seem to find the option which tells tsc to transpile the .map files to said directory.

Or so I have to do this manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052200/can-i-place-webpack-source-maps-and-source-code-files-in-seprate-folders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I place webpack source maps and source code files in seprate folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052200/can-i-place-webpack-source-maps-and-source-code-files-in-seprate-folders)