# Should I deploy sourcemaps to production?

Tags: javascript, webpack, deployment, source-maps, gatsby

I'm deploying my website - a static site built in GatsbyJS - and my sourcemaps are by far my largest files. I have 3 sourcemap files that are ~ 3MB. Overall they make up maybe 70% of my build.

- Should I deploy them to my production server?
- Are sourcemaps only downloaded by users that open devtools?

Comment: IMO no, you'd should be debugging stuff in dev or maybe even staging

Comment: See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345520/source-maps-files-in-production-is-it-safe  And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336028/any-legitimate-security-concern-with-making-javascript-source-map-public

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Considering [what a source map is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719562/javascript-map-files-javascript-source-maps) you just need to take into account that:

- If they are served publicly users can get access to your source code ([only if source map files are requested with the proper tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196117/why-using-jquery-map/27196201#27196201), of course).
- Need more disk space (in your case ~3 MB)

But, of course, you might need them on production mode in case you need to debug your application (on production mode, since they are not needed for debugging purposes on development mode) (See [Source maps files in production - Is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345520/source-maps-files-in-production-is-it-safe) and [Why use source maps in production?](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/419mgz/why_use_source_maps_in_production/)).

So, this decision is **completely up to you** according to your needs and requirements, having in mind the previously mentioned points.