# Are .map files necesaries in a React Production App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hosting

I want to know if the .map files are necessaries in the production mode, because when I convert my React App into production I get a .map file for every static file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source maps files in production - Is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345520/source-maps-files-in-production-is-it-safe)

Comment: They're useful for debugging your production code. If you open the devtools in Chrome, you won't be able to set a breakpoint because all your js files will be minified and impossible to read.

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks you