# Error.stack references only to main.chunk.js instead of real file name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, stack-trace

I am creating a React.js app in which I am getting the stack trace like this:

```
let trace = new Error().stack;
```

The app was created using `create-react-app`

When sending the trace to a server, I get these kind of lines:

> at onBlur (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:538:82)

At the line above, the `onBlur` is correct, but the file name is not.

Is there a way to get the name of the files as they are named in my project instead of `main.chunk.js` (which I assume is a compiled file created by webpack)?

Comment: Do you have source map generation disabled? You should already see file mapping for production builds. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904292/how-to-generate-sourcemaps-in-create-react-app

Comment: didn't know of something called a "source map" before your comment so no, i didn't disable it

Comment: @YonatanNir What version of `react-scripts` do you have in package.json and did you start it with `react-scripts start` (usually known as `start` in package.json scripts)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use npm package [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) - craco will allow you to specify webpack options without needing to eject the react application.

You can specify option devtool to control source code
here is `craco.config.js` file to preserve line numbers

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
      
        configure: {
            
            devtool: 'eval-source-map'

    }
    }
}
```

and you need to update package.json start script to

```
"start": "craco start"


function App() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let trace = new Error().stack;
    console.log('The link was clicked.' , trace);
  }

return (
        <button onClick={handleClick} > Blur</button>
)
}
```

You will see that original line number and file name are preserved.

[image]

Comment: I have given the reputation for this answer but did not actually test it so I did not accepted it. If someone can comment if it works, I can know if it should be accepted

Comment: dont use crago it is craco

Comment: @MuhZulzidan thank you for edit - I corrected the spelling.

Comment: on year and no one see it haha