# React17 console stack trace does not show line number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, stack-trace

I just migrated an app created with `create-react-app` from React16 to React17. Where before I had nice errors and warnings in my navigator console, with line number and links, I now have a reference to `index.js:1` and not so much info.
I tried to reproduce in a jsfiddle but it does not show the same.

I reduced my problem to the strict minimum. Here is how to reproduce:

- Initialise `create-react-app` with `npx create-react-app test17`
- Add a problem to `App.js`, like (this triggers a warning for the unique "key" prop):

```js
<ul>
{['a', 'b', 'c'].map((item) => (
<li>{item}</li>
))}
</ul>
```

- start and go to the console.

Here is what I get:
[image]

- now go to `package.json` and change the dependencies of `react` and `react-dom` from `^17.0.0` to `^16.0.0`
- remove `node_modules` directory and re-install (`nmp i`)
- start the server and go to the console

Here is what I get with React 16:[image]

As you can see, with React 16, I have the line number. And with more complete apps (with `react-router`, `material-ui` etc...), the links points directly to the error in the right file but now the error gives me that with React17:
[image]

I searched for solutions but found only few information or I did not understand it (I found someting about `ErrorBoudaries` but I don't think it matches what I'm looking for).

It might be linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620251/error-stack-references-only-to-main-chunk-js-instead-of-real-file-name) but I don't find any suitable answer.

Do you have any idea on how to make the stack trace more readable?